# How to uninstall Ubuntu 14 from Chromebook?

Tags: 14.04, chromebook

I have an Acer Chromebook 14 (CB3-431). I installed Linux with `crouton -r xfce and -t trusty`.

I think that it was version 14.04LTS. How can I uninstall Linux with command line in Chrome OS?

Answer (score 6):

To uninstall, we just need to delete the installation directory.

- To do this, <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+t</kbd> to enter terminal, start shell with 
  `shell` and press enter.
- Next, execute `sudo delete-chroot trusty`

This will remove the installed Ubuntu on chromebook.
To remove `crouton` tool, delete the `crouton` script under `/Downloads`.

---

Also, if not using any other OS with crouton, then enable the **OS verification** in Chrome OS by pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> while booting and accepting the change. Make sure to backup since turning on OS verification will cause loss of local data and Chrome OS will reset. (Any previous settings and Apps will installed after signing in and syncing again.)